# Can someone please explain how this implementation of bucket sort works?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm having a hard time understanding the underlying concepts of bucket sort, and I was hoping someone could clarify to me exactly what the sorting algorithm does and how it accomplishes the desired result (sorting an internal container) in O(N) time.  Also, as this seems to be quite fast, what advantages do other sorting algorithms (like bubble, insertion, or selection) have that would persuade one to use them over bucket sort?

Here is an implementation of the algorithm I found online.  If someone could reference this in their explanation I would greatly appreciate it.

```
void binsort(std::vector<std::size_t>& A){
    std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>> B(MAX + 1);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){
        B[A[i]].push_back(A[i]);
    }
    std::size_t current = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < MAX; ++i){
        for(auto item : B[i]){
            A[current++] = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your question how a bucket sort algorithm works in general, or just how *this* specific implementation of it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try and explain this specific implementation, which is one of the simplest you're likely to see. It not-coincidentally also has a hard restriction of allowable numbers in input domain as well (represented by the value `MAX`).

Suppose we have a collection of 10 numbers. the one attribute they share is that they are all in the domain [0..5]

```
{ 3, 2, 2, 5, 1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 4 }
```

Now, we create a "list" of buckets, where each bucket is represents a collection of values *from the domain; **not** the input array*. Our domain allows for 6 possible values, so we create six buckets (which are in "order", in case you don't notice that):

```
 0: {}
 1: {}
 2: {}
 3: {}
 4: {}
 5: {}
```

Now walk the input list, dropping each value in it's bucket. Conceptually it looks like this when finished:

```
 0: {0}
 1: {1}
 2: {2,2,2}
 3: {3}
 4: {4,4}
 5: {5,5}
```

Now, just walk our list of buckets, and dump the contents in each back into the original container, replacing whatever item was there.

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5}
```

Seems simple, yes? So why isn't everyone doing this for all their sorts? Well, consider we expand the problem. Instead of a `MAX` of 6 possible values, we make the 'value' bounded by `1048576` (2<sup>20</sup> in case you were wondering), **but keep the number of items sorted to just 10**.

Now, given the following list:

```
{ 3, 2, 2, 1048576, 1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 4 }
```

Our "bucket" list looks like this:

```
 0: {0}
 1: {1}
 2: {2,2,2}
 3: {3}
 4: {4,4}
 5: {5}
 6: {}
 7: {}
 .....
 1048575: {}
 1048576: {1048576}
```

Yeah, over a million buckets to sort ten numbers, all because that is the allowable max in our problem domain. Obviously this would not be feasible for large `MAX` ceilings. Sub-splitting the input range into manageable sets would be a viable solution to this (and in fact, is essentially how a *radix sort* works.

To answer your final set of questions, obviously if you had a reasonably small input domain, you would be hard to beat this for sort speed. For example, if we had a set of a thousand numbers, *all* of which were in `[0..9]`, this would be roaring-quick. Add a few orders of magnitude to that and it would be no comparison at all. However, the price, *the **heavy** price*, that you pay, is a restricted input domain. As the domain size rises, you have to approach it from a bucket-splitting algorithm perspective, and as you do so, you start down the path toward O(NlogN). Given that, there are *plenty* of algorithms (heap-sort, merge-sort, quick-sort, etc..) with their own set of caveats worth considering.

A place where it would be an obvious "win": Suppose you have to sort a million 8-bit characters (by definition a value in `[0..255]` ), you will not find a faster algorithm to do it. The domain is well-defined, very manageable, and if a proper table of "buckets" were utilized (literally a table of counters), I can't see it being beat.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) provides as an explanation. I hope this would be enough.

> Bucket sort, or bin sort, is a sorting algorithm that works by
>   partitioning an array into a number of buckets. Each bucket is then
>   sorted individually, either using a different sorting algorithm, or by
>   recursively applying the bucket sorting algorithm. It is a
>   distribution sort, and is a cousin of radix sort in the most to least
>   significant digit flavour. Bucket sort is a generalization of
>   pigeonhole sort. Since bucket sort is not a comparison sort, the Ω(n
>   log n) lower bound is inapplicable. The computational complexity
>   estimates involve the number of buckets.

Bucket sort works as follows:

1. Set up an array of initially empty "buckets."
2. Scatter: Go over the original array, putting each object in its bucket.
3. Sort each non-empty bucket.
4. Gather: Visit the buckets in order and put all elements back into the original array.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation given is pretty cool. So, if we have negative numbers, how do we handle that case ? One way to go about it is to keep a separate bucket list for negative numbers.

Imagine this data-set: { -5, -6, 5, 3, 6, -4 }

So here our "bucket lists" are the following:

List 1:

```
0: {0}
1: {0}
2: {0}
3: {1}
4: {0}
5: {1}
6: {1}
```

Bucket list 2:

```
-1: {0}
-2: {0}
-3: {0}
-4: {1}
-5: {1}
-6: {1}
```

So, if our case involves only integers our bucket lists do not even have to contain other lists. They can be just lists.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the case of negative numbers, you can select the smallest negative number and add that number to each elements in the array. 
`{-5,-6,5,3,6,-4}`has smallest element `-6`. Add absolute value of -6 to the array.
Array is now `{1,0,11,9,12,2}` Then sort it with the bucket array, which becomes `{0,1,2,9,11,12}` and to get final result add `-6` to each, thus `{-6,-5,-4,3,5,6}`. Performance wise  this is OK as subtraction and addition of the lowest range to the array is O(N).