# bucket sort gives the wrong results

Tags: c++

I have been trying to implement bucket sort using large size of random numbers example:"rand()%1000000
the issue is the results I get are wrong and are not listed correctly here is my code for bucket sort

```
void binsort(int arr[], int n){
int maxsize = 1000000;
int *b = new int[maxsize];

for( int i = 0; i <= maxsize;i++){

    b[i] = 0;

}
for( int i = 0; i <n;i++){
    b[arr[i]]++;
    }
for(int j = 0; j <n;j++){
    if(b[j] !=0){
        cout<<b[j]<< " ";
        }

    }
```

}
array will be filled with some value of  " int random_number = rand() %1000000

Comment: `for( int i = 0; i <= maxsize;i++){` You are stepping past the end of the array with <=. Better replace that with `for( int i = 0; i < maxsize;i++){`

Comment: Please refer to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082773/can-someone-please-explain-how-this-implementation-of-bucket-sort-works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample input output might help, but what is "if(b[j] !=0)" supposed to be doing here? I imagine print 0 when the count is 0 will give a more useful result.

edit: reading the code of the other answer.. it makes sense now, but his code is also missing a for loop lol.

```
void binsort(int arr[], int n){
int maxsize = 1000000;
int *b = new int[maxsize];

for( int i = 0; i <= maxsize;i++){
    b[i] = 0;

}

for( int i = 0; i <n;i++)
{
    b[arr[i]]++;
}

for(int j = 0; j <maxsize;j++){
    if(b[j] !=0){
        for (int k = 0; k < b[j]; k++){
        cout<<j<< " ";
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are few issues in your code. 
Here's the correct version

```
void binsort(int arr[], int n){
    int maxsize = 1000000;
    int *b = new int[maxsize];

    for( int i = 0; i < maxsize;i++){         //correct the condition
        b[i] = 0;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i <n;i++){
        b[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j <maxsize;j++){       //run the loop for maxsize
        if(b[j] !=0){
           //Edit: loop over count to print the numbers
           for(int k=0; k<b[j]; ++k) {
              cout<<j<< " ";         //print j not b[j]
           }
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: 
Forgot the case when there are duplicates in the array. Inner loop over 'count' takes care of it